# Site is broken on Microsoft Edge for Windows Mobile

Tags: support, bug, mobile-web, microsoft-edge

Things started breaking a few weeks back. On the mobile site the drop-down on my profile would no longer initiate a reload on change. I lived with having to manually enter the `?tab=responses` arguments, and moved along.

Today, however, things have gotten far worse. The site literally accepts no input any more. There's no way for me to comment on questions or answers, up- or down-vote contributions, close-vote, or even just get to my profile.

Clicking any widget/button/link that used to work just fine up to a week ago or so simply has the browser navigate to the top of the page, and that's it. This happens for the up-/down-vote arrows, edit/close/flag links underneath questions, the *"Add a comment"* link under questions and answers, and probably a lot more I haven't found out yet.

This made the site unusable from my mobile phone, running Microsoft EdgeHTML version 15.15254. I know, that's dated, and you kept telling me on the "full" page, that this browser were no longer supported. But I'm not using the "full" page on my mobile phone.

I understand that you (Stack Overflow) have been busy re-doing the site, moving towards a single implementation that works across all devices. Since I'm not a web developer, I may have missed why I should be all excited about this. The only thing I've seen so far is that the "full" site has degraded several times in terms of usability, and the mobile site has now completely locked me out.

I'd much appreciate if this situation could be resolved in a way that allows me to use the site from my mobile phone. If you cannot support a somewhat dated browser on the full site, at least keep the mobile version operational.

Is that asking too much?

Comment: Take a look at [this Meta SO post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/1081494). Tl;dr: "We support the last two stable versions of the browsers that we see the vast majority of our visitors actually use. This does not include beta, developer, nightly, canary, or any other pre-release versions of browsers, which are not supported." On my phone, I have Edge version 46.3.30. So... um... you probably need to update your browser. Version 15 is _far more_ than two behind 46. Moreover, Microsoft is slowly replacing Legacy Edge (EdgeHTML) with new Edge (Chromium-based). So you should just upgrade.

Comment: @coc *"So you should just upgrade."* - Sure, I'd love to! How do you do that on Windows 10 Mobile?

Comment: You have a Windows Phone, right?

Comment: No, I have a Windows 10 Mobile device. It's a Microsoft Lumia 950 XL.

Comment: Alright. I have no idea how to update, but someone on [Windows Phone SE](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions) might know. I'd ask with the [lumia], [windows-10-mobile], and the [microsoft-edge] tags, and see if someone knows. Of course, double-check that your question is on-topic there, first.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Lumia_950), the Lumia 950 used Windows 10 Mobile, which according to [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-mobile-end-of-support-faq-8c2dd1cf-a571-00f0-0881-bb83926d05c5) reached end of Support in December 2019; I suspect you are unlikely to be able to get any updates for your device.

Comment: *"If you cannot support a somewhat dated browser on the full site, at least keep the mobile version operational."* The "non-responsive" version of the sites in the community are (for lack of a better word) deprecated; they are no longer maintained and (despite the fact that you do still get pushed into the non-responsive sites from time to time on mobile) it is highly recommended you use the responsive site on your devices.

Comment: *"If you cannot support a somewhat dated browser on the full site"* I wouldn't say a version that was released in April 2017, and since then there have been **22** new version (including the change from EdgeHTML to Blink is "somewhat dated" either.

Comment: I don’t expect them to make an exception to their browser policy but I am deeply curious as to what’s happening that would prevent *all* input from working. (My guess with the links is some JS that’s too new to be supported.)

Comment: If you can’t update Edge, can you install a different browser?

Comment: The reason why it's no longer supported is that MS themselves made Edge into a Chrome clone. Worse is that Windows Phone is a dead project as well. I'm not sure the pre-Chrome Edge will be supported for much longer. Maybe try [Opera Mini](https://blogs.opera.com/mobile/2015/06/opera-mini-for-windows-phone/)?

Comment: @Opera - Legacy Edge (EdgeHTML) was discontinued completely this year.  There is zero support and it was removed completely from all supported versions of Windows. (If you were wondering). Legacy Edge on unsupported versions of Windows would be no different than a browser on Windows XP or Windows 7 from support ability standpoint

Comment: @lar *"I suspect you are unlikely to be able to get any updates for your device."* - I'm not asking for updates to my device. I'm asking to not break things for no reason. *"The 'non-responsive' version of the sites \[...\] are no longer maintained"* - Great. Not breaking things should then be easy. If you aren't doing anything, then nothing happens. *"I wouldn't say a version that was released in April 2017, and since then there have been 22 new version \[...\] is 'somewhat dated'"* - That's understood. "The Web" is just a garbage platform with respect to longevity.

Comment: @bsm *"can you install a different browser?"* - Such as?

Comment: @mac You mean that [Opera Mini](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/opera-mini/9wzdncrdmtk6)?

Comment: Sometjing that isn't supported any more is likely to break through @IInspectable, you've missed the point. It's precisely because it isn't supported that things are going to stop working, just like if you stop servicing your car it's likely to break down. The responsive site is constantly being updated, and the back end with it, the non-responsive is not though; there will literally be a point where it doesn't work at all because the 2 differ too much.

Comment: You might not like it, but the fault isn't with SO here, they can't be expected to support a 4 year old version of an unsupported browser that is running on an OS that also hasn't been supported for the best part of 2 years. The solution is to use a supported browser (and ideally a device that that is also using a supported  OS).

Comment: @llnspectable - At the end of the day legacy edge is unsupported on all versions of Windows (both traditional and mobile).

Comment: What do you mean “such as”? I was asking you.

Comment: To paraphrase Steve Jobs: "Just buy a new phone. Not that big of a deal." ;-) If you're like me, you're probably years out-of-date anyway and it's long past time, you've just been procrastinating until a good reason presented itself. Consider this your motivation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is asking too much. The computer industry moves too fast to expect support for unpopular platforms for more than a year after they've been removed from the marketplace. Microsoft [EdgeHTML version 15.15254 was released October 7, 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdgeHTML) according to Wikipedia and reached [End of Life on March 9, 2021](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/faq/internet-explorer-microsoft-edge) according to Microsoft. Windows 10 Mobile reached [End of Support on December 10, 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-mobile-end-of-support-faq-8c2dd1cf-a571-00f0-0881-bb83926d05c5) according to Microsoft, receiving no more security updates since then.

While it is your prerogative to continue using an insecure platform, no business has an obligation to support your use of that platform.

Maintaining versions of software, even keeping them on the server, has a non-zero cost to Stack Overflow. They absorb that cost, allowing people to continue getting the old version, since the cost, while not zero, is negligible.

Asking them to keep an eye on that unsupported code, to make sure that any stray referenced code might get updated for the new code base and break the old, is asking quite a bit. Especially for a platform that has been, for all intents and purposes, abandoned.